# Create combinations in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combinations, permutation

I've scoured the entire website trying to look for a macro (or function) that will create unique combinations from a given list in adjacent columns.

So basically, I have:

```
A  1  F1  R1  
B  2  F2  
C     F3  
D  
E
```

And I'm trying to list all the information as (in the same worksheet and in different columns):

```
A 1 F1 R1  
A 1 F2 R1  
A 1 F3 R1  
A 2 F1 R1  
A 2 F2 R1  
A 2 F3 R1  
B 1 F1 R1  
B 1 F2 R1  
B 1 F3 R1  
B 2 F1 R1  
B 2 F2 R1  
B 2 F3 R1  
...etc.
```

(added bonus for being able to toggle where the list is printed on the sheet)

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "unique combination" since your examples do not seem to show this working correctly as you are missing lots of values and are mixing items between rows.

Comment: What exactly do you have? Have you included the cell names in this list?

Comment: Are there always exactly 4 items in a set? Can the set have repetitions? In other words is A-A-F1-F1 a valid member? Is A-B-C a valid member? You need to be more specific about what constitutes a valid set.

Comment: sorry, i don't know why the formatting messed up when i posted.  
I meant A, B, C, D, E are all in Column A.  
1, 2 is in Column B.  
F1-3 is in Column C.  
and R1 is in Column D.  

I'm trying to create as many combinations as i can from the data.  

Also, the set cannot have values from the same column, it must use values from different columns and have exactly four items in the set @TylerDurden

Answer (score 2):

There's a workbook at https://app.box.com/s/47b28f19d794b25511be with both formula- and VBA-based methods to do that.

Comment: I didn't realize this is a two-year old post, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The code to get all possible combinations as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub Combinations()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim a As Range, b As Range, c As Range, d As Range
    Dim x&, y&, z&, w&

    For x = 1 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set a = ws.Range("A" & x)
        For y = 1 To ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set b = ws.Range("B" & y)
            For z = 1 To ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set c = Range("C" & z)
                For w = 1 To ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    Set d = ws.Range("D" & w)
                    Debug.Print a & vbTab & b & vbTab & c & vbTab & d
                    Set d = Nothing
                Next
                Set c = Nothing
            Next
            Set b = Nothing
        Next y
        Set a = Nothing
    Next x

End Sub
```

and the output

```
A   1   F1  R1
A   1   F2  R1
A   1   F3  R1
A   2   F1  R1
A   2   F2  R1
A   2   F3  R1
B   1   F1  R1
B   1   F2  R1
B   1   F3  R1
B   2   F1  R1
B   2   F2  R1
B   2   F3  R1
C   1   F1  R1
C   1   F2  R1
C   1   F3  R1
C   2   F1  R1
C   2   F2  R1
C   2   F3  R1
D   1   F1  R1
D   1   F2  R1
D   1   F3  R1
D   2   F1  R1
D   2   F2  R1
D   2   F3  R1
E   1   F1  R1
E   1   F2  R1
E   1   F3  R1
E   2   F1  R1
E   2   F2  R1
E   2   F3  R1
```

Comment: Hi @mehow I ran the macro, however it didn't output any results into the worksheet

Comment: @user2425910 it wasn't told to do so:) if you click `CTRL + G` before/after running the code you will open a window in the `VBE` view called `Immediate Window` which is a debbuging console for `VBA` and your output will be there. You can modify the `Debug.Print` to output to a worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Try this VBA code:

```
Type tArray
    value As String
    count As Long
End Type

Sub combineAll()
    Dim sResult(10) As tArray, rRow(10) As Long, str() As String
    Dim sRow As Long, sCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim resRows As Long
    sRow = 1: sCol = 1: r = 0

    With ActiveSheet
        Do
            rRow(sCol) = 1
            If (Trim(.Cells(sRow, sCol).value) = "") Then Exit Do
            Do
                If (Trim(.Cells(sRow, sCol).value) = "") Then Exit Do
                sResult(sCol).value = sResult(sCol).value & Trim(.Cells(sRow, sCol).value) & ";"
                sResult(sCol).count = sResult(sCol).count + 1
                sRow = sRow + 1
            Loop
            sCol = sCol + 1
            sRow = 1
        Loop

        Do
            r = r + 1
            For i = 1 To sCol - 1
                str = Split(sResult(i).value, ";")
                .Cells(r, sCol + i).value = str(rRow(i) - 1)
            Next i

            For i = sCol - 1 To 1 Step -1
                If rRow(i) < sResult(i).count Then
                    rRow(i) = rRow(i) + 1
                    Exit For
                Else
                    rRow(i) = 1
                End If
            Next i

            If rRow(1) >= sResult(1).count Then Exit Do
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```