# How can I generate all 4 card combinations of a 52 card deck using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, combinatorics

I am trying to generate all combinations of 4 cards using a deck of 52 cards. Generating all the permutations would be easy (and long), but in cards, the order doesn't matter, so for instance Ah,Kh,Qh,Jh would be the same as Kh,Ah,Qh,Jh. Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me some sample code that I can use? Found it weird that no one tried this before.

Comment: I think this is more a https://math.stackexchange.com question than a programming one.

Comment: One way (not very efficient) generate all permutations, sort **each permutation** (so `1234` and `4321` become both `1234`) and remove the duplicates.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It's a pure math problem if he's just looking to count the combinations.  If he wants to actually list them out as "A♥K♥Q♥J♥" etc for some reason then less so

Comment: What about suits?  Are 'Ah, Kh, 8d, 9d' the same as 'As, Ks, 8c, 9c' ?

Comment: No. Not the same. But I believe your solution covers that right?

Comment: @Chronocidal I would call developing an algorithm to calculate something a pure math problem at first. You need that algorithm first before you can start coding in any desired language. So I would say the first part is a math problem. An algorithm can be math too, it doesn't need to be done with code necessarily. There were many algorithms developed by mathematicians before coding even existed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combination Algorithm in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198154/combination-algorithm-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Have you done any research? This has been answered many times on SO.

Comment: Also see [Create combinations in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16820113/9898745)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 4 nested loops.  To prevent repeats and only count "unique sets", I think you just have to have each loop begins at:  `[the 'parent' loop's current value] + 1`

---

### Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub All4Combos()

    'Caution!  Save your work before runnning! (or set constant smaller)

    Const NumCardsInDeck = 52
    Dim c1, c2, c3, c4
    Dim p As Long

    For c1 = 1 To NumCardsInDeck
        For c2 = c1 + 1 To NumCardsInDeck
            For c3 = c2 + 1 To NumCardsInDeck
               For c4 = c3 + 1 To NumCardsInDeck

                    p = p + 1
                    Debug.Print c1, c2, c3, c4

                Next c4
            Next c3
        Next c2
    Next c1

    Debug.Print p & " Combinations of " & NumCardsInDeck & " cards"

End Sub
```

---

## Result:

Number of permutations:

```
52 x 51 x 50 x 49
```

Number of combinations:

```
Permuations / slots!
--OR--
(52 x 51 x 50 x 49) / (4 x 3 x 2 x 1)
```

The result is 270725 combinations.

Here's the result set with 10 cards:

```
1,2,4,10
1,2,5,6
1,2,5,7
1,2,5,8
1,2,5,9
1,2,5,10
1,2,6,7
1,2,6,8
1,2,6,9
1,2,6,10
1,2,7,8
1,2,7,9
1,2,7,10
1,2,8,9
1,2,8,10
1,2,9,10
1,3,4,5
1,3,4,6
1,3,4,7
1,3,4,8
1,3,4,9
1,3,4,10
1,3,5,6
1,3,5,7
1,3,5,8
1,3,5,9
1,3,5,10
1,3,6,7
1,3,6,8
1,3,6,9
1,3,6,10
1,3,7,8
1,3,7,9
1,3,7,10
1,3,8,9
1,3,8,10
1,3,9,10
1,4,5,6
1,4,5,7
1,4,5,8
1,4,5,9
1,4,5,10
1,4,6,7
1,4,6,8
1,4,6,9
1,4,6,10
1,4,7,8
1,4,7,9
1,4,7,10
1,4,8,9
1,4,8,10
1,4,9,10
1,5,6,7
1,5,6,8
1,5,6,9
1,5,6,10
1,5,7,8
1,5,7,9
1,5,7,10
1,5,8,9
1,5,8,10
1,5,9,10
1,6,7,8
1,6,7,9
1,6,7,10
1,6,8,9
1,6,8,10
1,6,9,10
1,7,8,9
1,7,8,10
1,7,9,10
1,8,9,10
2,3,4,5
2,3,4,6
2,3,4,7
2,3,4,8
2,3,4,9
2,3,4,10
2,3,5,6
2,3,5,7
2,3,5,8
2,3,5,9
2,3,5,10
2,3,6,7
2,3,6,8
2,3,6,9
2,3,6,10
2,3,7,8
2,3,7,9
2,3,7,10
2,3,8,9
2,3,8,10
2,3,9,10
2,4,5,6
2,4,5,7
2,4,5,8
2,4,5,9
2,4,5,10
2,4,6,7
2,4,6,8
2,4,6,9
2,4,6,10
2,4,7,8
2,4,7,9
2,4,7,10
2,4,8,9
2,4,8,10
2,4,9,10
2,5,6,7
2,5,6,8
2,5,6,9
2,5,6,10
2,5,7,8
2,5,7,9
2,5,7,10
2,5,8,9
2,5,8,10
2,5,9,10
2,6,7,8
2,6,7,9
2,6,7,10
2,6,8,9
2,6,8,10
2,6,9,10
2,7,8,9
2,7,8,10
2,7,9,10
2,8,9,10
3,4,5,6
3,4,5,7
3,4,5,8
3,4,5,9
3,4,5,10
3,4,6,7
3,4,6,8
3,4,6,9
3,4,6,10
3,4,7,8
3,4,7,9
3,4,7,10
3,4,8,9
3,4,8,10
3,4,9,10
3,5,6,7
3,5,6,8
3,5,6,9
3,5,6,10
3,5,7,8
3,5,7,9
3,5,7,10
3,5,8,9
3,5,8,10
3,5,9,10
3,6,7,8
3,6,7,9
3,6,7,10
3,6,8,9
3,6,8,10
3,6,9,10
3,7,8,9
3,7,8,10
3,7,9,10
3,8,9,10
4,5,6,7
4,5,6,8
4,5,6,9
4,5,6,10
4,5,7,8
4,5,7,9
4,5,7,10
4,5,8,9
4,5,8,10
4,5,9,10
4,6,7,8
4,6,7,9
4,6,7,10
4,6,8,9
4,6,8,10
4,6,9,10
4,7,8,9
4,7,8,10
4,7,9,10
4,8,9,10
5,6,7,8
5,6,7,9
5,6,7,10
5,6,8,9
5,6,8,10
5,6,9,10
5,7,8,9
5,7,8,10
5,7,9,10
5,8,9,10
6,7,8,9
6,7,8,10
6,7,9,10
6,8,9,10
7,8,9,10
210 Combinations of 10 cards
```

Comment: This doesn't have repeated 4-card sets.

Comment: @Vityata In a standard 52-card deck orderded 2♥-A♥,2♦-A♦,2♣-A♣,2♠-A♠ then A♥A♦A♣A♠ will be cards 13,26,39 and 52

Comment: That's wasn't specified in the question.  i asked for clarification.

Comment: Number of combinations without repetition where order does not matter can also be written as:
n! / r!(n - r)!. For n = 10 and r = 4 this (also) gives 210

Comment: While this works, it isn't very good for extending to the general case

Answer (score 1):

**For the fun of it**

Building on ashleedawg's code and writing the result to a text file I got this result:

```
Run took 2293 milliseconds
Wrote cardcombos.txt with 270725 lines of 4-card combinations of totally 52 cards
```

Porting the code to C++ yielded this:

```
Run took 203 milliseconds
Wrote cardcombos.txt with 270725 lines of 4-card combinations of totally 52 cards
```

Comment: So with the ampersands it took more time? Are you sure or your processor was doing something else as well?

Comment: Of course. a long integer require more space and more registers than an integer (not entirely true)

Comment: Dim c1 As Integer
    Dim c2 As Integer
    Dim c3 As Integer
    Dim c4 As Integer
I never use Dim alone. I always specify

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long

Comment: Well, VBA (.Net, C#) will not beat unmanaged code C(++). More than 10 times faster

Comment: I somehow missed your point. My initial idea was that if you declare the ashleedawg's variables like this `Dim c1&, c2&, c3&, c4&`, the VBA code will be faster than the VBA code is when the variables are `Dim c1,c2,c3,c4`.

Comment: New topic suggestion: Why do we need anything but C++?

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?
Nope!

Comment: Sometimes SO is killing herself

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an extended version of the "how many handshakes" problem....

There are a couple of ways to go about it - 1 would be to brute-force it (generate *all* permutations, sort the elements all into card/suit order, then delete duplicates)

A second option would be to create a deck and work through in order ("card `1` can be paired up with cards `2`-`52`, pair `1&2` can be triaded up with cards `3`-`52`, triad `1&2&3` can be quarteted up with cards `4`-`52`") and remove 'used' cards from the stack for the next loop ("triad `1&2&4` can be quarteted up with cards `5`-`52`, pair `1&3` can be triaded up with cards `4`-`52`, card `2` can be paired up with cards `3`-`52`")  This will then stop at quartet `49&50&51&52`

And, yes, it will take a long time for your workbook to work these out.  Not as long as the full 6,497,400 permutations, but there are still 270,725 combinations.

Comment: There are waaay more combinations than that.  `8.06e+67` of them.

Comment: Hmm no. There are 6497400 permutations (52x51x50x49) and 270725 combinations (52x51x50x49)/(1x2x3x4). His numbers are right.

Comment: @ashleedawg Take a 4-digit pin.  There are 10 options for the first digit, 10 for the second, 10 for the third, 10 for the fourth.  That's 10*10*10*10 = 10^4, not 10^10^10^10.  So, picking 1 card from each of 4 different decks would give 52^4, or 7,311,616 - since we are taking all 4 cards from the same deck the number *must* be smaller than that

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - My code was correct, I was doing the math wrong elsewhere!

Comment: About 2 seconds is not long for 270,725 combinations

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes to the code provided above. Here is the final result.

```
Option Explicit

Sub All4Combos()

Dim Cards() As String

'Caution!  Save your work before runnning! (or set constant smaller)

Cards = Split("As,Ks,Qs,Js,Ts,9s,8s,7s,6s,5s,4s,3s,2s,Ah,Kh,Qh,Jh,Th,9h,8h,7h,6h,5h,4h,3h,2h,Ad,Kd,Qd,Jd,Td,9d,8d,7d,6d,5d,4d,3d,2d,Ac,Kc,Qc,Jc,Tc,9c,8c,7c,6c,5c,4c,3c,2c", ",")
Const NumCardsInDeck = 51
Dim c1, c2, c3, c4
Dim p As Long
p = 0
For c1 = 0 To NumCardsInDeck
    For c2 = c1 + 1 To NumCardsInDeck
        For c3 = c2 + 1 To NumCardsInDeck
           For c4 = c3 + 1 To NumCardsInDeck

                p = p + 1
                Cells(p, 1) = Cards(c1) & Cards(c2) & Cards(c3) & Cards(c4)

            Next c4
        Next c3
    Next c2
Next c1


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If we split the cards by 4 suits, each with 13 cards and use this as our base,  then there are 5 different combinations of 4 cards, that can be withdrawn, if we only take care of the suits as uniqueness:

- ♥♦♣♠ - four different suits
- ♥♦♣♣ - three different suits
- ♣♣♥♥ - two different suits (2:2)
- ♣♣♣♥ - two different suits (3:1)
- ♥♥♥♥ - one suit only

Now, pretty much, if simulate all these possibilities for all suits, the sum of the 5 simulations should be equal to **(49x50x51x52)/(4x3x2) = 270725**

---

♥♦♣♠

```
For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
    For cnt2 = 1 To totalCards
        For cnt3 = 1 To totalCards
            For cnt4 = 1 To totalCards
                numberResult = numberResult + 1
            Next : Next : Next : Next
```

Four nested loops are exactly what is needed. With `totalCards=13` and `numberResult*4` for each suit, we get **28561**. Or `13^4`.

---

♥♦♣♣

```
For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
    For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
        For cntA = 1 To 3
            For cnt3 = 1 To totalCards
                For cnt4 = 1 To totalCards
                    numberResult = numberResult + 1
                Next : Next : Next : Next : Next
```

Here the idea is that for each two cards of the same suit, there is one suit, which does not take place in our calculation. Thus, the `cntA = 1 To 3`. At the end, we multiply by `4` for each suit to get **158184**.

---

♣♣♥♥

```
For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
    For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
        For cnt3 = 1 To totalCards
            For cnt4 = cnt3 + 1 To totalCards
                numberResult = numberResult + 1
            : Next : Next : Next : Next
```

We have 78 possibilities for 2 cards from the same suit. This is simulated with the first two nested loops. The other 78 possibilities for another color are with the next 2 nested loops. Thus, we have 6084 variations. However, the ways to combine 4 suits into a union of 2 are 6 (♥♣,♥♦,♥♠,♣♦,♣♠,♦♠), thus we multiply the result by `6` to get **36504**.

---

♣♣♣♥

```
For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
    For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
        For cnt3 = cnt2 + 1 To totalCards
            For cnt4 = 1 To totalCards
                numberResult = numberResult + 1
            Next : Next : Next : Next
```

Here we have 3 equal cards and one different. Per 1 suit of 3 equal cards, we may have 3 different cards. And we have 4 suits, thus, we have to multiply by `12` (4x3) to get **44616**.

---

♥♥♥♥

```
For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
    For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
        For cnt3 = cnt2 + 1 To totalCards
            For cnt4 = cnt3 + 1 To totalCards
                numberResult = numberResult + 1
            Next : Next : Next : Next
```

This is exactly like the accepted answer, but in this case our `totalCards = 13`. As far as we have 4 different suits, we multiply by `4` to get **2860**.

---

This is the result of the code:

```
 28561  4 different suits.
158184  3 different suits.
 36504  2(2:2) different suits.
 44616  2(3:1) different suits.
  2860  1 suit only.
270725  All.270725
```

Finally, here comes the code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt1&, cnt2&, cnt3&, cnt4&, cntA&
    Dim totalCards&: totalCards = 13
    Dim numberResult&, totalResult&

    '4 different suits
    For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
        For cnt2 = 1 To totalCards
            For cnt3 = 1 To totalCards
                For cnt4 = 1 To totalCards
                    numberResult = numberResult + 1
                Next: Next: Next: Next
    numberResult = numberResult
    Debug.Print " " & numberResult & vbTab & "4 different suits."
    totalResult = numberResult + totalResult
    numberResult = 0

    '3 different suits
    For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
        For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
            For cntA = 1 To 3
                For cnt3 = 1 To totalCards
                    For cnt4 = 1 To totalCards
                        numberResult = numberResult + 1
                    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    numberResult = numberResult * 4
    Debug.Print numberResult & vbTab & "3 different suits."
    totalResult = numberResult + totalResult
    numberResult = 0

    '2 different suits (2+2)
    For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
        For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
            For cnt3 = 1 To totalCards
                For cnt4 = cnt3 + 1 To totalCards
                    numberResult = numberResult + 1
                Next: Next: Next: Next
    numberResult = numberResult * 6
    Debug.Print " " & numberResult & vbTab & "2(2:2) different suits."
    totalResult = numberResult + totalResult
    numberResult = 0

    '2 different suits (3+1)
    For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
        For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
            For cnt3 = cnt2 + 1 To totalCards
                For cnt4 = 1 To totalCards
                    numberResult = numberResult + 1
                Next: Next: Next: Next
    numberResult = numberResult * 12
    Debug.Print " " & numberResult & vbTab & "2(3:1) different suits."
    totalResult = numberResult + totalResult
    numberResult = 0

    '1 different suit
    For cnt1 = 1 To totalCards
        For cnt2 = cnt1 + 1 To totalCards
            For cnt3 = cnt2 + 1 To totalCards
                For cnt4 = cnt3 + 1 To totalCards
                    numberResult = numberResult + 1
                Next: Next: Next: Next
    numberResult = numberResult * 4
    Debug.Print "  " & numberResult & vbTab & "1 suit only."
    totalResult = numberResult + totalResult
    numberResult = 0

    Debug.Print totalResult & vbTab & "All." & (49& * 50 * 51 * 52) / (4 * 3 * 2)

End Sub
```